# how to convert document.getElementById into jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code of mixed(jquery and javascript):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var mixedMode = {
          name: "htmlmixed",
          scriptTypes: [{matches: /\/x-handlebars-template|\/x-mustache/i,
                         mode: null},
                        {matches: /(text|application)\/(x-)?vb(a|script)/i,
                         mode: "vbscript"}]
        };
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("HTMLcodeMirror"), {
          mode: mixedMode,
          selectionPointer: true,
          theme: "eclipse"
        });

        var html = $('#HTMLcodeMirror').val();
        $('#html-output').html(html);
        $('.run-btn').click(function(){
          html = editor.getValue();
          $('#html-output').html(html);
          console.log('clicked');
          console.log(html);
        });
        console.log(html);
      });
```

Here I want to convert  `var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("HTMLcodeMirror"), {` as follows:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($("#HTMLcodeMirror"), {
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: textarea.getAttribute is not a function
    at Function.fromTextArea (codemirror.js?ver=1.0.0:9562)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (HTML.js?ver=1.1.4:9)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.1.1:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=3.1.1:2)
```

whats wrong in my code? Any idea?

Comment: `document.getElementById("HTMLcodeMirror")` = `$("#HTMLcodeMirror")[0]` So you should use `$("#HTMLcodeMirror")[0]`

Comment: Note `[0]` unwraps the jquery object and returns the underlying DOM element. You may or may not want this

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: If you want the attributes in "JQuery" use `.attr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromTextarea()` method expects a dom element not a jQuery object.

You can get the underlying dom element from `$("#HTMLcodeMirror")` several ways

The easiest is `$("#HTMLcodeMirror")[0]`

Can also use `$("#HTMLcodeMirror").get(0)`